# Java date with combobox item

Tags: java, date, combobox

I have a combobox fill date by database like this `2014-06-01 16:00:00` , and a `Date()`, how can i write that if `Date()` is now `2014-06-30 11:30:00`  and if the date in combobox is older than the today's date then delete item from combobox

in query Idő=date

```
fogcomb.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
            tesztvalt=(fogcomb.getSelectedItem()).toString();
            asd=fogcomb.getSelectedIndex()+1;
            if (e.getItem().equals(tesztvalt)) 
            fogcomb2.removeAllItems();
            {
              try {
                String sql="SELECT Idő,Terem,Leírás,IKód FROM Filmlista F,Idopontok I WHERE Cím like'"+tesztvalt+"'and I.FKód=F.FKód and I.FKód='"+asd+"'"; 

                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                    while (rs.next()) {

                        String name=rs.getString("Leírás");
                        String names=rs.getString("Idő");
                        String names2=rs.getString("Terem");
                        String names3="   ";
                        String names4=rs.getString("Ikód");
                        fogcomb2.addItem(names+names3+"@"+names2+" "+"@"+names4);  

                        foglab1.setText("<html>" + name  +"</html>");
                        foglab1.setFont (foglab1.getFont().deriveFont(15.0f));
                        foglab1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(""+tesztvalt+".jpg"));
                        szekfogborito.setIcon(new ImageIcon(""+tesztvalt+".jpg"));
                        szekfogcim.setText(tesztvalt);
                    }

                        }catch(Exception ex) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

                        }
```

Comment: Post some code or write a fiddle to show your exact problem.

Comment: my problem is that i dont know how to write that part, my combobox fill date by database and i want to that if selected date in combobox older than today's date then delete it from combobox

Comment: Why don't you query your DB in such a way that you get dates which are more than today's date?

Comment: can i write like this? i didnt know :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this condition in the query itself:

```
SELECT .... FROM TABLE WHERE yourDate > SYSDATE
```